# Interface behavior is dfferent in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Interface behaves differently in Vb.Net. Below is a sample code snippet where `IStudent` interface has a method `SayHello` which is implemented by a class `Student`. The Access modifier for `SayHello` should be `Public` by default. By changing Access modifier to `Private` is not breaking the existing code and still i can access this private method using below code

```
Dim stdnt As IStudent = New Student
stdnt.SayHello()
```

Access modifier determines the scope of the members in a class, more over private members are accessible only from the class which exists. But here the theory of Access Modifier, Encapsulation are broken.

- Why .net has designed in this way?
- Is the concept of Access modifier and encapsulation are really broken?
- How .net framework internally handle this situation?

Thanks in advance

```
Module Module1

   Sub Main()
        Dim stdnt As IStudent = New Student
        stdnt.Name = "vimal"
        stdnt.SayHello()
   End Sub

End Module

Public Interface IStudent

   Property Name As String

   Sub SayHello()

End Interface

Public Class Student
   Implements IStudent

   Private Property Name As String Implements IStudent.Name

   Private Sub SayHello() Implements IStudent.SayHello
       Console.WriteLine("Say Hello!")
   End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original poster submitted this question to me via TheBugGuys@Coverity.com; my answer is here:

https://communities.coverity.com/blogs/development-testing-blog/2013/10/09/oct-9-posting-interface-behaves-differently-in-visual-basic

To briefly summarize:

> Why was .NET designed in this way?

That question is impossibly vague.

> Is encapsulation broken by explicit implementation in C# and VB?

No. The privacy of the method restricts the accessibility domain of the methods *name*, not who can call the method. If the author of the class chooses to make a private method callable by some mechanism other than looking it up by name, that is their choice. A third party cannot make the choice for them except via techniques such as private reflection, which do break encapsulation.

> How is this feature implemented in .NET?

There is a special metadata table for explicit interface implementations. The CLR consults it first when attempting to figure out which class (or struct) method is associated with which interface method.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b3c4by9.aspx):

> You can use a private member to implement an interface member. When a private member implements a member of an interface, that member becomes available by way of the interface even though it is not available directly on object variables for the class.

In C#, this behaviour is achieved by implementing the interface explicitly, like this:

```
public interface IStudent {
    string Name { get; set; }
    void SayHello();
}

public class Student : IStudent {
    string IStudent.Name { get; set; }

    void IStudent.SayHello() {
        Console.WriteLine("Say Hello!");
    }
}
```

So, if you were to omit the `IStudent.` in front of the method names, it would break. I see that in the VB syntax the interface name is included. I don't know whether this has any implications altough. But interface members aren't private, since the interface isn't. They're kinda public...

Comment: Then why C# behaves different?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a C# alternative, although I'm not entierly sure whether it behaves this way.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The code I posted works perfectly. However, you can't put `private` in front of the methods. But you don't have to specify `public` either, so it's somewhere in between public and private...

Comment: All the members in a class implemented by an Interface should be public by default. Here the question is, Why the members are still accessible when the modifier gets changed to Private? Could you please try c# snippet without explicit implementation? It should not compile.

Comment: @VimalCK The point is that the VB syntax you showed is the equivalent to explicit implementation in C#.  The two snippets from each language are comparable.  If you change the C# code to not be an explicit implementation then you'd need to change the VB code as well for the examples to be comparable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no fundamental difference between C# and VB.NET, they just chose different ways to solve *ambiguity*.  Best demonstrated with a C# snippet:

```
interface ICowboy {
    void Draw();
}
interface IPainter {
    void Draw();
}

class CowboyPainter : ICowboy, IPainter {
    void ICowboy.Draw() { useGun(); }
    void IPainter.Draw() { useBrush(); }
    // etc...
}
```

VB.NET just chose consistent interface implementation syntax so the programmer doesn't have to weigh the differences between implicit and explicit implementation syntax.  Simply always explicit in VB.NET.

Only the accessibility of the interface method matters.  Always public.

Comment: Except that in VB, the access modifier only is relevant when *not* called via an object of the interface type.  What VB is doing is really creating 2 methods - one callable via the interface (where the access modifier is irrelevant), and one callable otherwise (where the access modifier is relevant).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: If `Foo` implements `IFoo`, with method `void Bar()`, then a definition `public void Foo()` is equivalent to `Public Sub Foo() Implements IFoo.Foo`, and `void IFoo.Foo()` is equivalent to `Private Sub xyzzy24601_IFoo_Foo_() Implements IFoo.Foo`.  Those are the only two patterns via which C# allows a method to implement an interface.  VB.NET allows other patterns as well, like `protected void ProtFoo() Implements IFoo.Foo`, whereas equivalent functionality in C# would require actually using two methods: `protected void ProtFoo() {...} void IFoo.Foo { ProtFoo(); }

Comment: @supercat: The 'private' example requires the same logic as your 'protected' example - you need to allow 'this' to access the method within the class without going through the interface to reproduce the VB 'Private' case.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: In VB.NET, if one declares the method `Private` one may use that member within the class using whatever name was specified.  In C#, the compiler doesn't let the programmer specify the name but instead arbitrarily invents one which may vary between compiles.  A method that explicitly implements an interface will generate an identifier in private scope, but without knowing what that name will be, the programmer can't refer to it except by examining the generated code and/or using Reflection.

Comment: @supercat: All I'm trying to show is that "void IFoo.Foo()" alone is not enough to provide an equivalent to "Private Sub Foo() Implements IFoo.Foo".  You also need "private void Foo()" to access within the class without an interface instance.

Answer (score 2):

When your variable stdnt is declared as IStudent, the interface methods and properties are then made Public, so the derived class' (Student) implementation is executed. If, on the other hand, if stdnt was declared as Student, the private members (Name and SayHello) would not be implemented, and an error would be thrown.

I'm guessing that the Interface members stubs (Name & SayHello) are by default Public, and the access modifier definitions of the derived class' implementation are ignored.

IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The exact equivalent in C# is the following - the method available to objects of the interface type and the private method available otherwise:

```
   void IStudent.SayHello()
   {
       this.SayHello();
   }
   private void SayHello()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Say Hello!");
   }
```

Comment: Look at the code I posted - that is the equivalent to the VB case where the access modifier is 'Private' - the method is still callable via an interface instance, but only within the class otherwise.

Comment: In other words, in both C# and VB, the method is always available via an interface instance.  In VB, the access modifier only applies to cases where the method is *not* called via an interface instance - you could call this bad language design on VB's part.