# Are there get and set methods for protected members of a class in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, class-members

Are there **get** and **set** methods for protected members of a class in C++/CLI like in [this example for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311017/4469411)?

```
private List<string> _myClassMember = null;

public List<string> MyClassMember
{
    get { return _myClassMember; }
    set { _myClassMember = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can create a property in C++/CLI that behaves just like the C# property in your question.

```
ref class MyClass
{
private:
  List<String^>^ _myClassMember = nullptr;

public:
  property List<String^>^ MyClassMember
  {
    List<String^>^ get() { return _myClassMember; }
    void set(List<String^>^ value) { _myClassMember = value; }
  }
};
```

Comment: You can even use an automatic property: `property List<String^>^ MyClassMember;` does the trick just like `List<String> MyClassMember { get; set; }` in C#.

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski: thanks! But using automatic property like you wrote it, in this example, it doesn't seem to refer to __myClassMember_ variable like in the non-automatic one. Or does it automatically find the variable it refers to by adding "_" to property name?

Comment: @Andrius no, the point of using the automatic property syntax is that you don't have to use any private variable anymore, one is created for you. It's just syntactic sugar. You always go through the property, and the JIT inlines the calls for you. Exactly like in C# actually.